# JsPsych - RT image audio response

Tags: javascript, jspsych

I am a newbie to jsPsych and am trying to build a language switching experiment  using Becky Gilbert's image audio response plugin: https://github.com/becky-gilbert/jsPsych/blob/audio-response/docs/plugins/jspsych-image-audio-response.md
I don't know how to get an accurate reaction time for each of my stimuli as the rt function in this plugin defines rt as the time between when the stimulus appears on screen to when the trial ends (rather than rt for each individual stimulus) .

When I run this example (with multiple stimuli), https://github.com/becky-gilbert/jsPsych/blob/audio-response/examples/jspsych-image-audio-response.html. The reaction time is the same for each stimulus even when I say nothing. I really don't know what to do :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your aim is here. The plugin works as expected: it allows you to record some audio when you display an image on the screen and the RT is the time when the participant progress to the next trial. If your aim is to detect when a participant stopped talking, you can use the audio data generated by the plugin to do some further processing and estimate that data yourself (e.g. adding an `on_finish` function, see [here](https://www.jspsych.org/7.3/overview/events/#on_finish-trial)). With this example, I hope it becomes clear that this is not something that the plugin can provide out of the box as different people can have different needs and different definitions of "rt".